# Samsung Galaxy 3 Apollo I58001 | Limited Internal memory problem

Tags: internal-sd

How do I solve the Limited Internal memory problem in my Samsung Galaxy 3 apollo I5801 device?
It has android 2.2 froyo and a 8gb micro SD card. I want to move the apps which are not by default movable to the SD card (not system apps).

Comment: Your selected tag seems not to match your question, or I am simply confused: could you please make clear what your question is? Am I correct it could be understood as "How do I move apps to SD (external?) which are by default not movable"? Would maybe the tags `external-sd` and `app2sd` match better then?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet might be to get an app to sd app off of the playstore.

Here's an app you can use.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd&hl=en

If you don't have enough memory to install it in the first place, check [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)